# How to make Java Anagrams from txt

Tags: java

I have Main class in Java. And need to write class Anagrams.
Main is:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

           String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
           String allWords = home + "/allwords.txt";

           Anagrams an = new Anagrams(allWords);

           for(List<String> wlist : an.getSortedByAnQty()) {
                 System.out.println(wlist);
           }

           System.out.println("************************");

           Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(home, "wordsToFind.txt"));

           while(scan.hasNext()) {
                 System.out.println(an.getAnagramsFor(scan.next()));
           }

           scan.close();
    }
}
```

For example:

> **File allwords.txt**:
>
> *andes danes deans evil gals lags levi live sedan
>   slag streets testers uprising veil vile*
>
> **wordsToFind.txt**:
>
> *evil streets uprising*

Then in the end we'll have:

> [evil, levi, live, veil, vile]
>
> [andes, danes, deans, sedan]
>
> [gals, lags, slag]
>
> [streets, testers]
>
> [uprising]
>
> ---
>
> evil: [levi, live, veil, vile]
>
> streets: [testers]
>
> uprising: []

I created class Anagrams and wrote a method that checks if words are anagrams. The metod returns boolen:

```
public static boolean IsAnagrams(String str1, String str2) {
        char word1[] = str1.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\W","").toCharArray();
        char word2[] = str2.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\W","").toCharArray();   
        Arrays.sort(word1);
        Arrays.sort(word2);
        return (Arrays.equals(word1, word2));

    }
```

But I don't understand what to do now.
I have to write methods:

- getSortedByAnQty() -- return list of anagrams
- String getAnagramsFor(String word) -- return list of anagrams for words from wordsToFind.txt

How can I do it?

Comment: for getAnagramsFor(String word) you could build a Map<String,List<String>> when you read allWords.txt.  Use the sorted version of each word as the key.  When you want to find the anagrams for a word just sort the letters and get the List<String> from the map.

Comment: What is getSortedByAnQty() supposed to do?  Can you give an example?

Comment: getSortedByAnQty() takes words from  allwords.txt and find anagrams. It was in first part of example. Like that: [evil, levi, live, veil, vile], [andes, danes, deans, sedan]. Method must return a list of anagrams.

Comment: In my understanding you have to produce every permutation of the "available" letters to get all anagrams for a word or sentence. I conclude from your sample "evil: [levi, live, veil, vile]" that you only want to accept permutations that are valid words, so you will need a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following code you get all character permutations of a word. If you flesh out isValidWord() you can reduce that set to words in your dictionary (allWords.txt?). The method builds up the permutations from the available characters so there is no need to check whether a permutation is an anagram.

```
public boolean isValidWord(String word) {
    return true; // return you dictionary check here
}

public Set<String> getAnagramsFor(String word, String letters) {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(); // no duplicates because of a letter occuring more than once
    if (letters.isEmpty()) {
        if (isValidWord(word)) {
            set.add(word);
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < letters.length(); i++) {
            String restOfLetters = letters.substring(0, i) + letters.substring(i + 1);
            set.addAll(getAnagramsFor(word + letters.charAt(i), restOfLetters));
        }
    }
    return set;
}

public void run() {
    System.out.println(getAnagramsFor("", "tea"));
    System.out.println(getAnagramsFor("", "foo"));
}
```

These test calls

```
    System.out.println(getAnagramsFor("", "tea"));
    System.out.println(getAnagramsFor("", "foo"));
```

print

```
[tea, aet, eta, ate, tae, eat]
[foo, oof, ofo]
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: As a second solution and regarding your restricted dictionary you can walk through your dictionary and check for every word whether it is an anagram of your word. In this code are both solutions, BTW here the original word is no longer part of the result set:

```
private List<String> wordsToFind = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "evil", "streets", "uprising" });

private List<String> validWords = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "andes", "danes", "deans", "evil", "gals",
        "lags", "levi", "live", "sedan", "slag", "streets", "testers", "uprising", "veil", "vile" });

public boolean isValidWord(String word) {
    return validWords.contains(word);
}

public Set<String> getAnagramsFor(String word, String letters) {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(); // no duplicates because of a letter occuring more than once
    if (letters.isEmpty()) {
        if (isValidWord(word)) {
            set.add(word);
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < letters.length(); i++) {
            String restOfLetters = letters.substring(0, i) + letters.substring(i + 1);
            set.addAll(getAnagramsFor(word + letters.charAt(i), restOfLetters));
        }
    }
    return set;
}

public Set<String> getAnagramsFor1(String word) {
    Set<String> anagrams = getAnagramsFor("", word);
    anagrams.remove(word); // remove original word from the result set
    return anagrams;
}

public boolean isAnagram(String str1, String str2) {
    char word1[] = str1.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\W", "").toCharArray();
    char word2[] = str2.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\W", "").toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(word1);
    Arrays.sort(word2);
    return (Arrays.equals(word1, word2));
}

public Set<String> getAnagramsFor2(String word) {
    Set<String> anagrams = new HashSet<>();
    for (String potentialAnagram : validWords) {
        if (!word.equals(potentialAnagram) && isAnagram(potentialAnagram, word)) {
            anagrams.add(potentialAnagram);
        }
    }
    return anagrams;
}
```

This test code

```
    for (String wordToFind : wordsToFind) {
        System.out.println(wordToFind + ": " + getAnagramsFor1(wordToFind));
        System.out.println(wordToFind + ": " + getAnagramsFor2(wordToFind));
    }
```

brings

```
evil: [veil, vile, levi, live]
evil: [veil, vile, levi, live]
streets: [testers]
streets: [testers]
uprising: []
uprising: []
```